# How do I grow primitive plants in Water Gels?

Tags: ferns

I have fern and horsetail spores. I have some Water Gels too. Can I grow fern and horsetails in Water Gels in a dry climate (not too dry, kind of moderate weather)?

Do I need a special fertilizer or anything?
(Can I grow these out of spores?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is new!  To WANT to plant horsetail is something I thought I'd never hear uttered.  If you plant horsetail DO IT IN A POT or an area that has metal down at least 1 1/2 feet into the ground.  Voracious plant considered a weed everywhere else.  If you are a gardener, horse tail can be dried, put into 'tea' to water other plants once or twice per year.  The silica from Equisetum makes other plants more hardy.  Bamboo is another plant that needs to be potted or inhibited from spreading.

Ferns need at least partial shade and clayish soils more moisture as well as a more acidic pH.  If you live in a hot, dry environment with sandy soils you will have to do some work.  Heavy shade and consistent moisture.  Not too much but those gells I'd throw out!  I wouldn't use them even in pots and baskets.  Ugh.  Just my opinion after trying them a few times and threw up my hands.  Make sure you do not use gravel or rock beneath the soil in pots but make dang sure that there is plenty of drainage and no sitting water.

Comment: So i cant use water gel beads and spores to grow them?

Comment: Not that I know about.  What is your ultimate goal?  If I were a plant I'd HATE these gells.  Where are the micro and macro organisms I NEED?  Granted, plants can grow in water...I'd rather grow in SOIL.  Healthy soil.  Let me know what you are trying to achieve!  Garden soil is NOT good in pots.  period.  But why are you thinking of these water gel beads?  I am interested what has interested you in these things.  I don't know everything no one really does.  What did you see to ask this question?

Comment: I have fern and horsetail spores and these plants need lots of water, so i thought water gel beads are good choice, really need to grow them out of tiny spores.

Comment: My only comment is that spores/seeds are used to growing in soil.  If not in the garden then in pots with sterilized potting soil, plenty of moisture, plenty of drainage and I'd include mycorrhizae (sp) and soil bacteria (lots of potting soils have these guys included).  Do not use garden soil in pots!!  I used those gel beads one time and vowed never to try again.  Ugh.  Vigilance, involvement (good water, not tap water) the best soil available without pathogens and a pot full of soil with NO  rock, gravel at the bottom for drainage (makes a perched water table)...

Comment: Oh and start out with TINY pots to start your spores.  As the plants grow simply transplant into a slightly bigger pot.  They have these Jiffy pellets that swell up with water and would be perfect for this job.  Also, use a plastic dome to keep temperature and moisture stable.  You can buy the entire kit.  I use these for starting all seeds especially those that might be sensitive to transplanting.  You can purchase 'Jiffy Greenhouses' for under 10 bucks or close.  Includes 72 pellets, a nice tray made to hold these pellets and the dome cover.  Careful to not water too much or get too hot!